# Inputting Firebase data inside Bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

Lately, I've been developing a website, and I'm using the Firebase Realtime Database to fetch some data inserted by the users previously and show them as Bootstrap Cards as seen on these images.

[Firebase Realtime Database - 1st card](https://ibb.co/wSBHCdM)

[Firebase Realtime Database - 2nd card](https://ibb.co/QrxXMvr)

[Bootstrap Cards](https://ibb.co/N2npmKJ)

However, I'm encountering a problem I'm unable to solve.

I've been trying to insert the rest of the data received by Firebase Realtime Database into a Bootstrap Modal dynamically so that the website's interface doesn't get overfilled, but I'm not being able to do it.

For example, if I [click](https://ibb.co/r6wnmb7) on the first card instead of seeing the "Ola" I've printed to test if the Modal text was working I would like to see inside the Bootstrap Modal: Feridos: "1-3" and if I click on the second card instead of seeing the "Ola" I would like to see inside the Modal: "Descrição: Testing"

I've created a JSFiddle with all of my code => [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d6neo7fw/1/)

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />       
    <title>Project</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="pagInicial.css"/>  
    <script type="module" src="denuncias.js"></script>
    <script type="module" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/firebase/8.2.2/firebase-app.min.js"></script>
    <script type="module" src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.1.3/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script type="module" src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.1.3/firebase-auth.js"></script>              
    <script type="module" src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.1.3/firebase-database.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-Fy6S3B9q64WdZWQUiU+q4/2Lc9npb8tCaSX9FK7E8HnRr0Jz8D6OP9dO5Vg3Q9ct" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-+sLIOodYLS7CIrQpBjl+C7nPvqq+FbNUBDunl/OZv93DB7Ln/533i8e/mZXLi/P+" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p id="avisoDenunciasVazio">Não existem denúncias para apresentar</p>
    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
          </div>
          <div id="dadosCardDenuncia" class="modal-body">
            <p>Ola</p>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container mb-5">
      <div id="cardsDenuncia" class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-md-4 g-4">
    </div> 
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
import { db, auth, firebaseRef, firebaseConfig, child, get, ref } from './firebase.js'

let listaDenuncias = []
const listaIDs = []
let tipoDenuncia = ''
let alturaOcorrencia = ''
let nome = ''
let horaDenuncia = ''
let dataDenuncia = ''
let idQueixa = ''
let feridos = ''

export function mostrarDados () {

  // Obter todos os registos das Denuncias
  get(child(ref(db), 'Denuncia/')).then((snapshot) => {
    // Limpar lista de denuncias
    console.log('Lista limpa')
    listaDenuncias = []
    $('#cardsDenuncia').empty()
    adicionarDados(listaIDs)

    if (snapshot.exists()) {
      document.getElementById('avisoDenunciasVazio').style.display = 'none'
      snapshot.forEach(childSnapshot => {
        console.log('childSnapshot: ' + JSON.stringify(childSnapshot))

        childSnapshot.forEach(dadosSnapshot => {
          console.log('aux: ' + JSON.stringify(dadosSnapshot))
          console.log('aux.key: ' + JSON.stringify(dadosSnapshot.key))

          dadosSnapshot.forEach(element => { 
            console.log('idQueixa: ' + JSON.stringify(element.key))
            idQueixa = element.key

            console.log('Tipo Denuncia: ' + JSON.stringify(childSnapshot.key))
            tipoDenuncia = childSnapshot.key

            console.log('Altura Ocorrencia: ' + JSON.stringify(dadosSnapshot.key))
            alturaOcorrencia = dadosSnapshot.key

            console.log('Data: ' + JSON.stringify(element.child('dataDenuncia').val()))
            dataDenuncia = element.child('dataDenuncia').val()

            console.log('Hora: ' + JSON.stringify(element.child('horaDenuncia').val()))
            horaDenuncia = element.child('horaDenuncia').val()

            console.log('Nome: ' + JSON.stringify(element.child('nome').val()))
            nome = element.child('nome').val()
            
            feridos = element.child('feridos').val()

            if (alturaOcorrencia === 'Quero dar a Conhecer') {
              listaDenuncias.push({ idQueixa, tipoDenuncia, alturaOcorrencia, dataDenuncia, nome: 'Anónimo', horaDenuncia })
            } else {
              listaDenuncias.push({ idQueixa, tipoDenuncia, alturaOcorrencia, dataDenuncia, nome, horaDenuncia })
            }
          })
        })
      })
      console.log('listaDenuncias: ' + JSON.stringify(listaDenuncias, null, 4))
      listaDenuncias.forEach(function (dados) {
        adicionarCards(dados.idQueixa, dados.tipoDenuncia, dados.alturaOcorrencia, dados.dataDenuncia, dados.horaDenuncia, dados.nome)
      })
    } else {
      console.log('Nao tem dados')
      document.getElementById('avisoDenunciasVazio').style.display = 'block'
    }
  }).catch((error) => {
    console.error('Erro =>' + error)
  })

  function adicionarCards (idQueixa, tipoDenuncia, alturaOcorrencia, dataDenuncia, horaDenuncia, nome) {
    const card = `<div class="col-md-4" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
              <div id="${idQueixa}" class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h2 class="card-title">Denuncia</h2>
                  <div class="d-flex flex-column">
                    <p class="card-text aumentar-row"> Tipo: ${tipoDenuncia} </p>
                    <p class="card-text diminuir-row"> Ocorrência: ${alturaOcorrencia} </p>
                    <p class="card-text diminuir-row"> Data: ${dataDenuncia} </p>
                    <p class="card-text diminuir-row"> Hora: ${horaDenuncia} </p>
                    <p class="card-text diminuir-row"> Nome: ${nome} </p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>`

    document.getElementById('cardsDenuncia').innerHTML += card
    listaIDs.push(card)
  }

  function adicionarDados (listaIDs) {
    $('#exampleModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
      const dados = `<p>Feridos: ${feridos}</p>`
      document.getElementById('dadosCardDenuncia').innerHTML = dados
    })
  }
}

$(document).ready(function () {
  mostrarDados()
})
```

I'll provide any extra code if needed.
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've solved my issue with this piece of code on JS

```
...
    function adicionarDados (idQueixa) {
        feridos = listaDenuncias.at(this.idQueixa).feridos
        $('#exampleModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
          const dados = `<p>Feridos: ${feridos}</p>`
          document.getElementById('dadosCardDenuncia').innerHTML = dados
        })
...
```